# WordPress Multisite redirection loop in /wp-admin/network on Centos 7 VestaCP + NGINX + PHP-FPM

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, multisite, vesta

I've runned across issue with *Wordpress Multisite*.

The project is **WordPress Multisite with Subdomains**, running on the same `/` root folder.

1. **Multisite #1**: https://one.sub.domain.com
2. **Multisite #2**: https://two.sub.domain.com
3. **Multisite #3**: https://three.sub.domain.com
4. **Main Domain**: https://sub.domain.com

VPS is running Centos 7 with VestaCP. We are using NGINX for web-service. Project runs via SSL (https://).

Basically whenever I try to visit **Main Domain** Network Dashboard https://sub.domain.com/wp-admin/network i get redirection error.

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

I've checked and outruled following possible issues:

- Not a file/folder permission issue (files have `0644` and folders `0755` + it's assigned to *VestaCP* username `domain_user`)
- Not a WordPress configuration or database error.
- All *nginx* and *php* log files are empty/no errors showing.

I suspect it's due to issue in nginx `subdomain.domain.ssl.conf` config file but I can't figure out what exactly. Here is the content of the config file - it is by default the **VestaCP Web Template**: `Wordpress2_rewrite`

```
server {
    listen      37.201.93.62:443;
    server_name sub.domain.com one.sub.domain.com two.sub.domain three.sub.domain;
    root        /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/sub.domain.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/sub.domain.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/sub.domain.com.error.log error;

    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/domain_user/conf/web/ssl.sub.domain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/domain_user/conf/web/ssl.sub.domain.com.key;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9002;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page  403 /error/404.html;
    error_page  404 /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }

    location /vstats/ {
        alias   /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/stats/;
        include /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/stats/auth.conf*;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    include     /home/domain_user/conf/web/nginx.sub.domain.com.conf*;
}
```

This works fine on `/wp-admin` hovewer not on `/wp-admin/network` URLS
This is configuration `wp-config.php` file content:

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'ARhaa6zreusFJ2VWkuP+l+v]&JEa3kQ|HUn4[|PA:E%k&B|J_mm-?s---&Hew0x7');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '$23xN:I#`0vQDff_t5Ogk*--h,:^@-0>r6_#,eQL=bc(##uwO&+|i]I<7[KpB%.?');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '9c3qJwhQxx:`|gP^.Y6>d{.;(,95#x@fgHH~#/?>K_jie<iz$mgD1E y;!|Nr~LV');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '<8Dh+67o;Pg7m_=++wa!0G+~H$p#Fq|ytwA,fBu~e}9`P.m|;?2&-^wM@Rq~[=?<');
define('AUTH_SALT',        ')*YP~hQ]sRn0;^+ApMmj/$);<~?:>vHhc080or<}MRM$a4#%*CEkC//;~GAFzP^-');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'uX|45M7~=xKJo`GIoE|:;A[Dl2Sg.Z?w^+HfgLMF3*f5`h*>MT] j7.% X_t6n{7');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'I!NZC^][EM-<+d_6j3G{l2-0ba16YEM-&z$|Y`8qM>/<M]GPz)::~b/|+xPigr?u');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '-Vw#PgM@)P|2+U_x]J! 4+F-IZpe+y@Z~W}({D lPOHTH8hq%=#mse.77Ziw@);{');


/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');

/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'sub.domain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);


define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' )
{
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']       = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

I've double checked - this config works fine and doesn't cause any issue.

At this point I'm really lost and can't figure out how to fix the issue.
Whenever I try to visit https://sub.domain.com/wp-admin/network/update-core.php i am redirected to https://sub.domain.com/wp-admin/network and get redirection error:
[image]

I'm hoping on your help! Thanks in advance.

**[EDITED]**

I just noticed when visiting https://one.sub.domain.com Dashboard and hovering for Network link, it returns https://wp-admin/network/ which clearly shows misconfiguration of nginx.

**[Possible issue & solution]**

Soo i debuged once again and my `wp-content/debug.log` contained these lines

```
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:19 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
[07-Jan-2019 23:55:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'domain' of non-object in /home/domain_user/web/sub.domain.com/public_html/wp-admin/network/admin.php on line 20
```

And in `/wp-admin/network/admin.php` file I commented out `line 20`:

```
$redirect_network_admin_request = 0 !== strcasecmp( $current_blog->domain, $current_site->domain ) || 0 !== strcasecmp( $current_blog->path, $current_site->path );
```

which fixed the issue, but clearly it will mess up the **Network Admin Request Redirection** soo now the question is - **HOW TO FIX THIS PROPERLY?**

Comment: Weird request, but what happens if you change the `location / {... try_files...` rule to the following: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` ? As I've had something similar happen (*although not a multi-site setup*) happen. Also, do your logs mention anything at all?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried it but still the same error. No. nginx and php logs are clean. no errors at all (i updated details in post above).

Comment: Can you try to set network `BASE_URL` in `wp-config.php` file? I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: @AshiqurRahman nope. as I said. it's not the WordPress issue - it's probably misconfigurated nginx config file.

Comment: Try to set the network base url &  other multisite URL both in wp-config.php &  DB table wp_options. I was faced this problem in aws using bitnami wp multisite. You can give it a try. It's the WordPress issue I think so.

Comment: @AshiqurRahman I've updated - i found the issue. It may be the base url issue, i'll try.. but it seems to be WordPress bug.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue. Commenting out line 20 lets me access the network admin area - but that does not seem a viable solution.

Comment: @goehler this was almost 4 years ago, and temp fix is in bottom of question. What WordPress version are you using? Pretty sure this should be fixed in 6.1.1. version.